# What is causing my Grid custom renderer for Xamarin.Android to throw this exception?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The exception is:

```
System.MissingMethodException
Constructor on type 'MyApp.Droid.MyGridRenderer' not found
```

The custom renderer:

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Util;
using MyApp;
using MyApp.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Grid), typeof(MyGridRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class MyGridRenderer : ViewRenderer<Grid, Android.Views.View>
    {
        protected MyGridRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have Visual Studio Community for Mac version 7.3.2

Just in case, this is the custom renderer for iOS, which is working ok without any constructors:

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using CoreText;
using Foundation;
using MyApp;
using MyApp.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Grid), typeof(MyGridRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class MyGridRenderer : ViewRenderer<Grid, UIView>
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of the constructor for Android custom renderers changed in the latest version (2.5.0) of Xamarin forms to require the context to be passed.

[You can see that here in the release notes.](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.5/2.5.0-stable/)

This is not something that is required for iOS.

Try changing protected to public.